# save arrays in dictionary using for loop in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, dictionary

I have a sheet with arrays with data that I want to save in a dictionary. The column space between each array is constant and the tables are similar size. I have names on top of each array (first one in cell J3) that should be the key and the data should be the item. How can I create a loop that saves all arrays and stops when the selected range is empty?

```
 Sub Dictionary()

    Dim dictionary() As Dictionary
    
    Dim nCol As Integer, i As Integer
    nCol = 13
    
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Range(Cells(27, 11), Cells(36, 21)).Activate
   
    For i = 1 To nCol
'        dictionary(i) = Selection.Value
        Selection.Offset(RowOffset:=0, ColumnOffset:=nCol).Select
    Next i
   
    
 End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: "the tables are similar size" What size are they ? "first one in cell J3" Where is the second and third ones, what is the pattern ?

Comment: What are you referring to when say "I have a sheet with arrays"? Do you know what a VBA array is? Are you referring to ranges, in fact? A dictionary must have a key and a value. If the value should be one of these "arrays", how do you intend to identify each such arrays from the dictionary? Don't you like to use that names (starting from "J3")? If so, please better describe the "arrays" meaning and their size. Of course, to be able to identify the next name, too. How to get the second one, the third and so on? I mean, based on what logic?

Comment: @CDP1802 my first range is from K27:U36 and then jumps the nCol which is 13. The same with the names (key)

Comment: @FaneDuru is want to use the names as key. First one starts in J3 and jumps 13 col to the next. The loop must stop when the next cell is empty.
The arrays/ranges are similar sizes and they are placed next to each other. The range must also jump 13 col to the right. I hope it makes sense

Comment: @CDP So the second table name is in W3 and the data is X27:AH36 ( that is 11 columns, by 10 rows). Correct ?

Comment: @CDP1802 Yes that is correct

Comment: Please, test the code I posted and send some feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, test the next code. It needs a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime':

```
Sub RangesIndictionary()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, dict As New scripting.dictionary, nCol As Long
    Dim i As Long, rngInit As Range, rngKey As Range, keyName As String
    
    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
    nCol = 13

    Set rngKey = sh.Range("J3")
    keyName = rngKey.Value
    Set rngInit = sh.Range(sh.cells(27, 11), sh.cells(36, 21))

    Do While keyName <> ""
        dict.Add keyName, rngInit
        Set rngKey = rngKey.Offset(0, nCol)
        keyName = rngKey.Value
        Set rngInit = rngInit.Offset(0, nCol)
    Loop
    Debug.Print dict.count & " ranges have been placed in the dictionary"
    Debug.Print "The first range is " & dict(sh.Range("J3").Value).Address
 End Sub
```

It may work using Late binding, but it is better to use the reference and benefit of the intellisense suggestions.

If it is possible that the name to be the same for two such ranges, the code  should preliminary check if the key exists. And you must tell us how to be treated such a situation.

In order to automatically add the necessary reference, please firstly run the next code:

```
Sub addScrRunTimeRef()
  'Add a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime':
  'In case of error ('Programmatic access to Visual Basic Project not trusted'):
  'Options->Trust Center->Trust Center Settings->Macro Settings->Developer Macro Settings->
  '         check "Trust access to the VBA project object model"
  On Error Resume Next
  Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll"
  If err.Number = 32813 Then
        err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
        MsgBox "The reference already exists...": Exit Sub
  Else
        On Error GoTo 0
        MsgBox """Microsoft Scripting Runtime"" reference added successfully..."
  End If
End Sub
```

It will remain only if you save the working workbook...

Comment: Thank you @FaneDuru I have tested the code and adding the reference gives me an error (Name conflicts with existing module, project, or object library).
I can still run the first part and the names are set as items and not key in the dictionary. And I'm not getting the data in the dictionary. This is my first time using dictionarys so maybe I'm missing something

Comment: I am driving now. I will reply after some hours, when I will be at home.

Comment: @FrankOlsen Firstly, the error only means that the reference already exists. I can adapt the code to announce it. Secondly, did you test the code **as it is**?  If not, please, try it exactly as it is. If not modified, the above code, the names certainly are dictionary keys. Using `Dict(key)` returns the dictionary `Value` for the respective key. If used as it is, did the code raise any error? If not, didn't it return in `Immediate Window` the numbers of ranges in dictionary and the address of the first range? For `Immediate Window` press `Ctrl + G`, being in VBE...